# Powershell Compare 2 CSV but highlight duplicates or create a new column

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm trying to compare 2 csv files and highlight the duplicates or add a separate column flag with text to let them know it is a duplicate. Right now I can generate a separate csv with only the changes but I would like to keep everything in the original csv and I just wanted to see if it could be done.

Here is my code to remove the duplicates into another csv:

```
$csv2 = (Import-Csv -Path \.csv).Primaryemail

$removedDuplicateRows = Import-Csv -Path \.csv | Where-Object {$_.Associate_Email -in $csv2}

$removedDuplicateRows | Export-Csv -Path \.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Csv doesn't do _highlight_.. Its just a structured set of data

Comment: Have you looked up the `Compare-Object` cmdlet yet? It's really helpful and much faster than `-in`. `$csv2 | Compare-Object $csv2 -Property { if ($_.Primaryemail) { $_.Primaryemail} else { $_.Associate_Email } } -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent`